# ラベルなしのセンサデータを使って、分類を行いたい

Tags: python3, 機械学習, chainer

ある論文のコピープロジェクトで、耳の中にセンサーを組み込み、表情認識を行う(何もしていない時の出力は0、大きく口を開けた時は1)ということを実装しようとしています。

[chainerでニューラルネットワーク簡単実装(初心者向け)](https://to-kei.net/python/machine-learning/chainer-neural-network/)

上記のサイトを参考にして、ラベル付けされたセンサデータ(フォトリフレクタ、0.1s*20=2s)をまとめたcsvファイルで学習を行いました。
今、その学習済みモデルにArduinoからの2秒間のデータをシリアル通信でリアルタイム(厳密にはリアルタイムではありませんが)に入力させ、表情認識を行おうとしています。
ただ、上記のサイトのコードだとラベル付けされたデータでしか、出力を吐き出してくれません。
つまり、ラベル付けされたデータの答え合わせをしてそのラベル付けがあっているかどうかを判定することしかできません。

**ここから、コードを改変して、ラベルのないセンサの値のみのデータを利用して、それがどの表情なのかを出力するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？**

Arduinoからの値でなくても、ラベルのないcsvファイルを読み込み分類できれば、そのcsvの部分をArduinoの読み込みに変えればいいので、とにかくラベルなしのデータが読み込めればいいと思ってます。

ちなみに、今の状態で1行20列のcsvデータを読み込もうとすると、もう１列のデータを要求されます(つまり、ラベル値の列が足りないということです)

Comment: やりたいのは教師無し学習なのに、参考にしているソースコードは教師有り学習、という状況ではありませんか……？

Comment: @nekketsuuu
回答ありがとうございます。
Tensorflowの話になってはしまうのですが、以前「Tensorflow活用ガイド」のサンプルコードをもとに教師あり学習を行い、モデルをTFLiteに変換した後、RaspberryPiでラベルなしセンサデータを取得してリアルタイム分類を行ったので、学習の問題ではないと思ってました。
学習はラベル付きで、分類はラベルなしのデータで行いたいという状況です。
その認識がそもそも間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick ♦
編集ありがとうございます。

Comment: なるほど、つまり、学習済みモデルを使って実際に分類を行いたいが、学習時に使ったコードをどう転用すれば良いか分からないというご質問ということで良いでしょうか。特にリンクされているブログ記事の「分類機を別のデータに適用して予測」の部分のソースコードですかね。

Comment: そうなりますね。サンプルで予測に使ったCSVファイルにはラベルの列(diseaseの列)があります。それをなしで分類を行いたいです。
その列を削除するとおそらくですが、
Expect: x.shape[1] == W.shape[1]
Actual: 4 != 5
と表示されるはずです。

Comment: 私の予測プログラムだと、20列のセンサデータ＋1列のラベルデータで学習したので、 Expect: x.shape[1] == W.shape[1] Actual: 19 != 20とエラーが吐き出されます。

Comment: まだ手元で試していませんが、`outputArray = model.predictor(data).data` までは実行されていませんか？　どの関数呼び出しの部分でエラーが起こっていますでしょうか。

Comment: おっしゃってる部分でエラーが吐き出されます。その前の段階までは問題なく動きます。

Answer (score 0):

参考にされているサイトでは、質問者さんのデータには無い分類データ `disease` の列を `predictor` に渡す直前で削除しています。

```
#入力データをnumpy配列に変更
data = np.array(df.iloc[:,:-1]).astype(np.float32)
```

このコードをそのまま流用しているのであれば、ここで最後の列を削除しないようにすれば良いです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
分類データの最後の列を削除しない理由は何故でしょうか？

学習の際に、csvファイルの`disease`属性をLabel属性に変えました。
そして、最後の列を削除せずに、推論のコードを実行すると、`'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Label'`と属性を求められます。そもそもラベルありのデータをこのエラーでは求められてるので、今回の主旨とはずれたエラーです。(センサーのデータはLabel列はそもそも削除済みで、ラベルがない状態です)
推論の際には属性のないセンサーのデータを送るので、学習の際に属性のないcsvファイルで学習すべきだと言うことでしょうか？そもそも、ラベルなしのデータで分類するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Comment: 分類データの最後の列を削除しないのは、CSVに `disease` の列が存在しないのに最後の列を削除してしまうと、必要なはずのデータ列（ブログ記事の通りなら `weight` ）を削除してしまうからです。

Comment: `result = pd.concat([pd.disease, ansDF, outputDF], axis=1)`
の`df.disease`が悪さをしてたみたいです。これがラベルを要求する原因になっていました。
サンプルでdf.diseaseはなぜ必要だったのでしょうか？？

Comment: ソースコードのコメントに書いてあるとおり、真の値を使って正解数、正答率を表示しているからです。

Comment: なるほど。理解しました。
丁寧に説明してくださり、有り難うございました。